# Dictionary with nested categories from a single list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list which is structured as follows:

```
arr = [ ['a'],
                ['a','b'],
                ['a','x','y'],
                ['a','c'],
                    ['a','c','a'],
                    ['a','c','b'],
                        ['a','c','b','a'],
                        ['a','c','b','b'],
                ['a','d'],
            ['b'],
                ['b','c'],
                    ['b','c','a'],
                    ['b','c','b'],                  
            ['c','d'],
                ['c','d','e'],
                ['c','d','f'],
                    ['c','d','f','a'],
                    ['c','d','f','b'],
                        ['c','d','f','b','a'],
                ]
```

As you would observe that the list has some unique elements and then following elements are building upon the unique element till a new unique element appears. These are supposed to categories and subcategories. So [a] , [b] , ['c','d'] are the broad level main categories and then there are further sub categories within sub categories based on the same priciple as above. Ideally I want the categories and sub categories as a dictionary. the end result should look something like:

```
{'a': ['a-b',
     'a-x-y',
     {'a-c': 
           ['a-c-a',
            {'a-c-b':
                    ['a-c-b-a', 
                     'a-c-b-b']
            }]
     }
    ],
'b' : ................
'c-d': ...............}
```

I may also be able to work with just the first level of sub-classification and discarding the rest altogether. In that case, the output would be:

```
{'a': ['a-b', 'a-x-y', 'a-c', 'a-d'], 'b': ['b-c'], 'c-d': ['c-d-e', 'c-d-f']}
```

I have written a code for the second scenario but I am not sure if this is a robust way to solve this:

```
def arrange(arr):
cat = {"-".join(arr[0]): ["-".join(arr[1])]}
main = 0
for i in range(2,len(arr)):
    l = len(arr[main])
    if arr[main] == arr[i][0:l]:
        cat["-".join(arr[main])].append("-".join(arr[i]))
    else:
        cat["-".join(arr[i])] = []
        main = i
for k,v in cat.items():
    found = True
    i = 0
    while i < len(v)-1:
        f_idx = i + 1
        while  v[i] in v[f_idx]:
            v.pop(f_idx)
        i += 1
return cat
```

> Output-:

```
{'a': ['a-b', 'a-x-y', 'a-c', 'a-d'], 'b': ['b-c'], 'c-d': ['c-d-e', 'c-d-f']}
```

Please help me make this code better and or help me with a dictionary that has the complete structure where I have all the sub-classifications. Thanks

Comment: This function returns `None` when I run it with your sample input data. Could you show the output you're getting?

Comment: oops sorry forgot return cat at the end. that might be it. when i run it i get

{'a': ['a-b', 'a-x-y', 'a-c', 'a-d'], 'b': ['b-c'], 'c-d': ['c-d-e', 'c-d-f']}

Comment: At least for the input size you provided, I'd say this is pretty robust. You can use this method to profile the function as you scale up the input size: https://gist.github.com/JacobIRR/318143230a6ced24ce82882079b7ae10  `len` and `join` are used most often.

Comment: I see .. thanks. Any ideas on how can I make a dictionary with all sub-categories?

Comment: I'll keep staring at it, but I don't yet understand what's going on with the indentation and how that influences the output

Comment: oh, indentation is just for better visualization. I indented the list to just show where a new sub-category is. So the elements before the indented element would be the subcategory and all things indented are elements in that sub-category. hopefully, that makes sense.

Comment: @commonsensei: Finally , I believe I've what you describe as  first level of sub-classification and discarding the rest altogether. Pls. check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I believe I've what you describe as  first level of sub-classification and discarding the rest altogether.

The trick was to create action  based upon  when an item in the list (keys) was not a sublist of subsequent items (values).
The same logic was used for removing duplicates.

```
from collections import defaultdict

#Function that compares two lists even with duplicate items
def contains_sublist(lst, sublst):
    n = len(sublst)
    return any((sublst == lst[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(len(lst)-n+1))

#Define default dict of list
aDict = defaultdict(list)
it = iter(arr)

#Format key 
key = '-'.join(next(it))
s = list(key)

# Loop that collects keys if key is not sublist else values
for l in it:
    if contains_sublist(l, s):
        aDict[key].append(l)
    else:
        key = '-'.join(l)
        s = l

#Loop to remove duplicate items based upon recurrance of sublist
it = iter(aDict.keys())
for k in it:
    dellist = []

    for s in aDict[k]:
        for l in aDict[k]:
            if l != s:
                if contains_sublist(l, s):
                    if not l in dellist:        
                        dellist.append(l)
    for l in dellist:        
        try:
            aDict[k].remove(l)
        except ValueError:
            pass

#Create final dict by concatenating list of list with '-'
finaldict = {k:[ '-'.join(i) for i in v ] for k,v in aDict.iteritems()}
```

**Result:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> finaldict
{'a': ['a-b', 'a-x-y', 'a-c', 'a-d'], 'b': ['b-c'], 'c-d': ['c-d-e', 'c-d-f']}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @ Anil for taking the time to write the code. I will take a look at it in the evening. Meanwhile i condensed my solution for this further. Feel free to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a [`Trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Here's a very basic implementation:

```
def make_trie(words):
   root = dict()
   for word in words:
       current_dict = root
       for letter in word:
           current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(letter, {})
       current_dict[1] = 1
   return root

trie = make_trie(arr)
print(trie)
# {'a': {1: 1, 'c': {'a': {1: 1}, 1: 1, 'b': {'a': {1: 1}, 1: 1, 'b': {1: 1}}}, 'b': {1: 1}, 'd': {1: 1}, 'x': {'y': {1: 1}}}, 'c': {'d': {1: 1, 'e': {1: 1}, 'f': {'a': {1: 1}, 1: 1, 'b': {'a': {1: 1}, 1: 1}}}}, 'b': {1: 1, 'c': {'a': {1: 1}, 1: 1, 'b': {1: 1}}}}
print(trie.get('a',{}).get('x',{}))
# {'y': {1: 1}}
```

This trie is just nested dicts, so it's easy to iterate over all the children of `['a', 'x']` or select all the dicts that have a max-depth of 2 for example.

`1` is used for leaf words: for example if you have `['a', 'x', 'y']` as sub-array, but not `['a', 'x']`.

There are more complete Trie libraries for Python, such as [pygtrie](https://github.com/google/pygtrie).